# Fix repeated keystrokes without destroying AutoHotkey scripts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey, repeat-rate

I have a mechanical keyboard problem where sometimes one key press registers as two. I solved this by installing *Keyboard Chattering Fix* and setting a minimum 50 ms delay requirement between key presses.

The issue is that this ruins my [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) scripts which require the ability to type really quickly.

So is there another way to fix my keyboard issue?

Comment: You can have the AHK scripts kill the process, then restart it.

Comment: @Gantendo A good idea, but some of my AHK scripts are rather low-latency and need to be pressed/activated multiple times within the space of a 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the chattering fix in AutoHotkey itself (instead of using *Keyboard Chattering Fix*, which presumably is a separate utility), then you wouldn't break anything else you have running in AutoHotkey.

I have done something similar to this by just defining a bunch of hotkeys to rate limit how fast they can be detected or sent. Your mileage may vary.

**Hotkey Definitions**

```
Space::ti92_rateLimit(needBrackets:=True)
a::rateLimit()
b::rateLimit()
...
z::rateLimit()
```

You can see that this might break down when using modifiers. You could also try variations on the hotkey to detect the modifiers and use `*` in the hotkey definition instead, but I'm not sure how extensive of a fix you need.  If you go this route and want to debug, add a `ToolTip` or `MsgBox` into the `rateLimit()` routine to display `A_ThisHotkey` when called.

**Code**

```
rateLimit(needBrackets:=False) {
    static lastHotkey
    static lastCall

    if ((lastHotkey=A_ThisHotkey) && (lastCall-A_TickCount)>50))
        SendInput % needBrackets ? "{" A_ThisHotkey "}" : A_ThisHotkey

    ;Sleep 20   ; output rate limit

    lastHotkey:=A_ThisHotkey
    lastCall:=A_TickCount
}
```